# What is the Sampling Design and how to take sampling weights?

Tags: sampling, survey-sampling

I wan to know what is is the sampling design here (situation is also depicted in the figure below)

- City is divided into urban and rural domains
- Each domain is divided into blocks
- Each block contains houses
- Urban ––> Randomly Selected 2 Blocks ––> Randomly Selected 5 Houses from each Block
- Rural ––> Randomly Selected 3 Blocks ––> Randomly Selected 5 Houses from each Block

[image: pling]

Comment: Blocks have more than houses on them. So, commercial areas, have small and many large businesses. Also, houses in such commercial areas are not  similar to houses found in neighbors. I see the logic of an aerial designed frame, but better may be a stratified sampling approach from the property tax records. But, I am unclear on the attributes to be assessed, which is important in the design of the frame.

Comment: Is this a homework question?

Comment: No this is not a homework question @astel

Answer (score 1):

This looks like, stratified two-phase cluster sampling. You've stratified into urban/rural and then you select blocks (clusters). You then sample households within each block which means you are doing two-phase cluster sampling (one-phase would mean you just take all the households in the block).

The simplest way to determine survey weights would be to just use the inverse of the probability of selection which should be easy to calculate.